# How to keep some bookmarks expanded/open and some closed?

Tags: pdftex, bookmarks

(On `pdflatex`) I have used `\usepackage[open,openlevel=1]{bookmark}` to keep bookmarks expanded by default. But I need to keep some bookmarks closed  (i.e. contracted) by default.
I add bookmarks by hand like this:

```
\documentclass[pdftex]{book}
\usepackage[a4paper,landscape,margin=3cm]{geometry}
\usepackage[open,openlevel=1]{bookmark}

\begin{document}
This is Part 1
\addcontentsline{toc}{part}{Part 1}\\
This is Chapter 1 of Part 1
\addcontentsline{toc}{chapter}{Chapter 1}
This is Chapter 2 of Part 1
\addcontentsline{toc}{chapter}{Chapter 2}
\clearpage
This is Part 2
\addcontentsline{toc}{part}{Part 2}\\
This is Chapter 1 of Part 2
\addcontentsline{toc}{chapter}{Chapter 1}
\clearpage
This is Chapter 2 of Part 2
\addcontentsline{toc}{chapter}{Chapter 2}
\clearpage
This is Part 3
\addcontentsline{toc}{part}{Part 3}\\
This is Chapter 1 of Part 3
\addcontentsline{toc}{chapter}{Chapter 1}
\clearpage
This is Chapter 2 of Part 3
\addcontentsline{toc}{chapter}{Chapter 2}
\clearpage
\end{document}
```

Now I want to keep `Part 2` and `Part 3` Expanded by default while `Part 1` will be contracted by default.

I searched but found no suggestion.

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! Please help us help you by providing a minimal compilable code example (MWE).

Comment: Thanks, I have edited and added a compilable code.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It is in fact possible to keep bookmarks closed on some level **on opening** of documents, but of course not any longer after users have clicked on the relevant level or on a reload of the already opened document within the PDF viewer application.

`\bookmarksetup{open=false}` issued at the top level (i.e. part) will keep the bookmarks closed until some other `\bookmarksetup{open=true, openlevel=X}` occurs.

`-1` usually is meant for part - level, `0` for `chapters` etc.

Following code hides the bookmarks for the 1st part and 4th part by default and the section(s) of the 2nd part, where as the section(s) in the 3rd. part are opened.

It works at least with `okular`, but only on opening of the document -- a simple reload does not revert to the original settings.

It does not work with `evince`, however. I have no other PDF viewers at hand to test.

```
\documentclass[pdftex]{book}
\usepackage[a4paper,landscape,margin=3cm]{geometry}
%\usepackage[bookmarksopen,bookmarksopenlevel=5]{hyperref}
\usepackage[open,openlevel=1]{bookmark}

\begin{document}
This is Part 1
\bookmarksetupnext{open=false}
\addcontentsline{toc}{part}{Part 1}
This is Chapter 1 of Part 1
\addcontentsline{toc}{chapter}{Chapter 1}
This is Chapter 2 of Part 1
\addcontentsline{toc}{chapter}{Chapter 2}
\clearpage
\bookmarksetup{open=true,openlevel=0}% Only open down to chapter
This is Part 2
\addcontentsline{toc}{part}{Part 2}
This is Chapter 1 of Part 2
\addcontentsline{toc}{chapter}{Chapter 1}
And a section...
\addcontentsline{toc}{section}{Section 1 of chapter 1 of part 2}
\clearpage
This is Chapter 2 of Part 2
\addcontentsline{toc}{chapter}{Chapter 2}
\clearpage

This is Part 3
\bookmarksetup{open=true, openlevel=1}% Open down to section level (i.e. 1)
\addcontentsline{toc}{part}{Part 3}
This is Chapter 1 of Part 3
\addcontentsline{toc}{chapter}{Chapter 1}
\clearpage
This is Chapter 2 of Part 3
\addcontentsline{toc}{chapter}{Chapter 2}
And another section
\addcontentsline{toc}{section}{Section 1 of chapter 2 of part 3}
\clearpage
% Hide again in bookmarks
\bookmarksetup{open=false}
This is Part 4
\addcontentsline{toc}{part}{Part 4}
This is Chapter 1 of Part 4
\addcontentsline{toc}{chapter}{Chapter 1}
\clearpage
This is Chapter 2 of Part 4
\addcontentsline{toc}{chapter}{Chapter 2}
\clearpage

\end{document}
```

[image: Bookmark Result]

Comment: Please no complaints about the manual `\addcontentsline` - statements. Those are kept intentionally since it is not clear why the O.P. introduced them.